# How to prevent ASP.NET MVC 5 from redirecting the user to the login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application written using c#. Some of the endpoints are used for the app itself while others are for API calls only. The API endpoint return `JsonResult`.

I want the API to always return `JSON` instead of redirecting when the user has not logged in or the user is unauthorized.

So I created a new Authorize-Attribute called `ApiAuthorizeAttribute` which I would use only on my API endpoints.

Here is how the `ApiAuthorizeAttribute` class looks like

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            int httpCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = httpCode;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new BaseResource(false, httpCode, "Request Forbidden. You must first login!")
                )
            );
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();

            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(httpCode);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }                
    }
}
```

However, even if the user is unauthorized, the framework will still redirect the user to the login page which I am trying to avoid. I can see that the request is going to the `if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated`) {...}` part of my code, by it still redirects the user to the login page.

**Updated**

If I uncomment the `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();` line and step through the code using Visual Studio. The page displays my JSON correctly. But then when the code finish calling the "Dispose()" method in the controller, I get `The connection was reset` error from my browser, which appears to be a redirection error of some sort.

How can I correctly prevent the framework from redirecting the user?

Comment: So you have an `[Authorize]` tag on the controller?  You could put an `[AllowAnonymous]` tag on the action.  In truth, I would recommend separating the endpoints in different controllers but you don't have to.

Comment: I only use the `[Authorize]` tag on the non-api endpoint. For the `api` endpoint, I use `[ApiAuthorize]`. Although it is irrelevant, I do have separate controller for my API end point.

Comment: What is the version of .Net you are targeting and what is the version of IIS you are running?

Comment: @zaitsman 4.5.1

Comment: and IIS version?

Comment: I am running it locally from Visual Studio so it would be IIS Express.

Comment: After restarting VS, I am now getting `The connection was reset` error. It looks like the request is being printed on the browser and then very quickly I get this `The connection was reset` error. So there is a redirect problem  and if I remove the `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();` line I get redirected to the login page. I am going to update the question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was because I am returning a 401 error code. So Instead this is what I changed my code to

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            int httpCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new BaseResource(false, httpCode, "Request Forbidden. You must first login!")
                )
            );

            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }                
    }
}
```